# When flying into the US, where do I go through customs?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

Flight from Atlanta to Minneapolis-St. Paul and connecting flight to Calgary. From Atlanta do I fly out of the domestic or international terminal? Where do I go thru customs?

Comment: There is, in general, no such thing as a "domestic terminal" or "international terminal" in the US.

Answer (score 1):

Atlanta has only one terminal, domestic and international together. They do have separate check in lobbies, one for domestic and one for international, but flights to Canada are considered "domestic" (though they won't really care if you check in at the international lobby either).

You will clear immigration and customs in Calgary.  There are no exit formalities from the USA.

Comment: In any case, the flight from Atlanta is going to Minneapolis, not Calgary. So even if there were a distinction, it would be domestic.

Comment: When a domestic flights connects with an international flight on the same ticket, the entire booking is considered "international travel" and the originating check in agent is required to verify international documents.  So if the OP is a foreign national, their departure from the USA would be reported by the Atlanta check in process not Minneapolis.

Comment: That's true. What I mean is, even if Atlanta did have a separate international terminal, the flight to Minneapolis would still leave from the domestic terminal, regardless of the fact that one of the passengers happens to be traveling onward to Calgary.